# Ionic 5 Native File plugin not writing files to dataDirectory

Tags: javascript, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to read and write files on the user's device. I'm using the Ionic File plugin, but whenever I try to create or write files, it gives no error, but does not create them.

The code that writes the files is a simple function only executing one line:

```
file.writeFile(file.dataDirectory + folderName, fileName, data, { replace: true });
```

Again, this code gives no errors, But when I navigate over to the folder on my phone `Android/my.app.id/files/`, the folder is empty.

I've tried changing my config.xml file as suggested by other forum posts by adding:

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="file://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

I've also tried using the other directory options in the plugin, but am met with `ENCODING_ERR`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found the solution. I just set the directory to `externalDataDirectory` instead of `dataDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

for android 10 add set this flag requestLegacyExternalStorage to true




for android 11 you need The new MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE